# Store char arrays address in new array

Tags: c++, c, arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

I have an included file in an Arduino program. MCU is ESP32.

included file is:

```
const char bitmap_1587[] PROGMEM = {248,254,254,230,241,231,247,199};
const char bitmap_1604[] PROGMEM = {249,254,254,254,0,191};
const char bitmap_1575[] PROGMEM = {7};
const char* char_addr[] = {&bitmap_1587,&bitmap_1604,&bitmap_1575};
```

When i compile the code, this error is returned:

> cannot convert 'const char (*)[6] to  'char*' in initialization

> cannot convert 'const char (*)[6]' to 'char*' in initialization

> cannot convert 'const char (*)[1]' to 'char*' in initialization

Please help me. How can i store char array address in an other array.

Comment: Undefined behaviour in case of signed char overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be correct:

```
const unsigned char bitmap_1587[] PROGMEM = { 248,254,254,230,241,231,247,199 };
const unsigned char bitmap_1604[] PROGMEM = { 249,254,254,254,0,191 };
const unsigned char bitmap_1575[] PROGMEM = { 7 };
const unsigned char* char_addr[] = { bitmap_1587,bitmap_1604,bitmap_1575,bitmap_1605,bitmap_32,bitmap_97,bitmap_98,bitmap_99,bitmap_1777,bitmap_1778,bitmap_1779 };
```

- you need `unsigned char` because you have values > 127
- you need to remove the `&`s, `bitmap_1587` etc. are already addresses
- you need `const char* char_addr[]` because you have `const` for the `bitmap_...` arrays.